# Cannot find amazing Buddhism resource with a sequence of instructions/guidance by level

Tags: reference-request, vipassana

I've previously come across an incredible Buddhism resource that has escaped me. It was a website with a non-modern design, plenty of sub pages that were formed in a sequence in terms of how to study buddhism.

In particular:

- there were different "levels" at which different techniques were appropriate and articles were split by the stages/levels
- for each of these levels there were a lot of comparisons (e.g., what type of problem/need you can remove at that level, what meditation is applicable at level, the Truths, the Paths)
- it was illustrated with quotes and pictures from the masters and written in Buddhist language, not a beginner-friendly wikiHow-like style
- it was quite an extensive resource

The closest comparison I've found is the [Basic Buddhism Guide](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/basic-guide.htm) on Buddhanet , but was I'm looking for was a less modern website, with more pictures and written in a more traditional style.

Comment: What tradition was it? Theravada, Mahayana, Tibetan, Zen? Maybe details like this could help people locate it?

Comment: Absolutely - I'm 90% sure it was Vipassana, 10% chance it was Zen! Sorry wish I could remember precisely, it's between those two though.

Comment: As for the 1. Step: [Better to Give than to Consume](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/bettertogive_en.html). The next would come by given cause.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot in the dark as I am not sure how well it matches your description, but could it be this? https://studybuddhism.com/

That site used to have an older version that was decidedly less modern and had the feeling of a much older website, but it has been updated recently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing, unfortunately not this one, it was a lot less modern and the language was more traditional (as if taken from a Buddhism book), but the content was similar in structure.

Answer (score 0):

Could be this:

https://accesstoinsight.org/

It’s Theravadan.

Comment: I don't think that describes "different levels" etc., nor say much about meditation, nor have pictures -- (which were all part of the OP's description).

Comment: That's right :(, it's not the one.